# Custom fault type for an ASP.NET webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I am developing a webservice in C#, ASP.NET. By default, when my webservice throws exception, using

```
throw new SoapException("ERROR_MESSAGE", SoapException.ClientFaultCode);
```

This outputs the following xml:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring>ERROR_MESSAGE</faultstring>
         <detail/>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

However, I have to implement a custom fault type that uses different xml:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body xmlns:cst="http://cust.om/Namespace">
      <cst:Fault>
         <cst:errorMessage>ERROR_MESSAGE</cst:errorMessage>
      </cst:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

They expect that this fault type appears also in the wsdl file that is generated by http-GETting ?wsdl, surfacing there as  element.

Is this even possible? Well, everything is possible by rewriting the exiting stream with replaced string, but I'd prefer less brutal approach. Besides, that kind of fix would not cause the  elements to appear in the auto-generated wsdl spec.